# Evaluating Mahout based Recommender Implementation

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm using mahout 0.7 for the implementation of the recommender system.

Ro evaluate the quality of the provided recommendations I'm using the `AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator` which allows me to evaluate MAE (Mean Average Error). When I use the AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator, the MAE values seems to be normalized between 0.0 and 1.0. But if I choose the `GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender`, the values are not within 0.0 and 1.0.

If I increase the percentage of the training dataset , the evaluation value is bigger with `GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender` which refers to poor recommendation.

This is how I evaluate the recommender:

```
RecommenderEvaluator evaluator = new AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator();
      RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
      public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) throws TasteException {
            ItemSimilarity similarity = new EuclideanDistanceSimilarity(model);
            return new GenericItemBasedRecommender(model, similarity); // or GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender
      }
};
double evaluation = evaluator.evaluate(recommenderBuilder, null, model, 0.7, 1.0);
```

Why the `AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator` with the `GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender` produces not normalized values, and how can I interpret  them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluator has nothing to do with it. It is not meaningful to asses mean absolute error with a boolean-data recommender. Mean average error is between actual and predicted rating, but there are no ratings.

Instead, the input is assumed to have rating "1". The predicted 'rating' in this case however is not a quantity that carries meaning, although higher means stronger.

You have to use precision/recall metrics or similar ranking metrics instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will run few tests with the RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator to evaluate precision/recall.

Comment: I've tried running the RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator for the GenericBooleanPrefItemBasedRecommender and I'm always getting 0 on precision and recall. I'm using the 100k MovieLens data set. Do you know what causing this behavior?